# como cargar una pagina distinta de acuerdo a lo elegido en el "select"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

tengo una webapp de google, en la cual poseo un select y deseo que cuando el usuario haga click en el boton (en este caso "buscar info") me cargue una nueva pagina con la info de lo seleccionado en el "select" .
Ejemplo: si el usuario elige "ingles" que se cargue una pagina con los dias y horario del cuso de ingles (informacion q tengo un en sheet)
y asi con los demas idiomas.

idiomass.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> eligir Idioma</h1>
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    
    <select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Ingles</option>
  <option value="value2" selected>Italino</option>
  <option value="value3">Aleman</option>
</select>
<label>Elija idioma por favor</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<button id="btn">Buscar Idiomas</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

codigo.gs

```
    function doGet(e){

return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('idiomass').evaluate();

}
```

idiomaIngles.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> eligio Ingles</h1>
    <select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Martes 10 hs</option>
  <option value="value2" selected>Martes 12 hs</option>
  <option value="value3">Jueves 11 hs.</option>
</select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Me parece que lo que estás preguntando ya lo respondí en la pregunta enlazada arriba. Si la pregunta referida no te ayuda, te sugiero editar esta pregunta indicando si tu duda está en el código de un archivo .html o en el .gs. P.S. Te falta incluir JavaScript en el archivo `idiomass.html`.

Comment: Puedes poner un data attribute a cada option con la url

Comment: @HernánGarcia Eso no funciona con archivos .html de Google Apps Script.